# Transaction recorded in audit log but missing from database - MariaDB 10.4.12

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

We have seen a weird situation where the DML's are written to the audit logs with retcode 0(meaning success) but were not executed inside the database. I have analysed the binary logs generated during that time and the count of statements from binary logs is less than the count of statements from audit logs... These are batch inserts into a simple innodb table without any foreign key references etc..
In audit logs we got 3131 batch insert statements where as in binary logs we got just 2323.

We are using MariaDB community server 10.4.12 version on Debian 10 with sync_binlog=1 and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1.

Does anyone faced similar situation? Looking for some insights on this issue..

I checked the configuration settings of database and could not find anything which is against the ACID properties of the database.

Thank you
Jaya

Comment: Are these partitioned tables ([MDEV-7451](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7451))? I couldn't see any other bug related. But I suggest grabbing a new instance (of a later version 10.4.14 was 3 years ago), and trying to reproduce it with a smaller dataset that you can audit to binlog events individually. When you have something repeatable, raise a bug report.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the comment, these tables are not partitioned..I don't think I can repeat this ..